# Can I create a bootable distribution backup

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, backup, gnome-shell, bootable

I'm interested in trying out a couple of distributions, but for extended periods of time (so using a LiveCD is not really an option).

However, I would like to create a backup of my current distribution (Ubuntu-Gnome) with it's settings and extra packages/dependencies.

Would it be a case of simply backing up a list of packages and settings folders (if so which ones) and reapplying these to a new installation, or can I create my own bootable installation?

Comment: why is using a live cd not an option? most livecds allow you to have some kind of persistency where changes will be written to a blockdevice

Comment: I just figured that booting from a live cd for a few weeks would ultimately be a slower/more painful experience.

Answer (score 0):

Create a full system backup using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or similar. If you have enough storage you could clone your current distro and any others you test to (for example) a removable hard drive and restore whichever one you prefer.